# What the `ipa` pipeline is about in CUDA architecture?

Tags: cuda, nsight

When looking into `ncu --query-metrics` it turns out that several counters are about this `ipa` pipeline that isn't even cited in [NSight docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/index.html#metrics-guide), `smsp__inst_executed_pipe_ipa` for example. While for all of the other pipelines a proper explanation is provided, for `ipa` I wasn't able to find any reference at all.

Answer (score 2):

IPA is the Interpolate Attribute pipeline used in pixel/fragment shaders to interpolate a varying attribute over a quad (4 threads). This pipeline is not accessible to a compute shader.